# Number of primitive roots $\pmod{m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find the number of primitive roots $\text{mod} 1300$

I thought this was calculated using $\phi (\phi (m))$ but I get that there are $128$ primitive roots, where as the solutions say there are none? Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive roots $\pmod{n}$ are those $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ that generate the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^\times$.  Note that primitive roots will therefore only exist when $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is a cyclic group.

It is a theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is a cyclic group $\iff$ $n$ is $2$, $4$, any power of an odd prime or twice any power of an odd prime.

Well, $1300 = 2^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 13$.

Answer (score 3):

The formula that you used would give correct answer, if the group $G=\Bbb{Z}_{1300}^*$ were cyclic. Alas that is not the case. This follows for example from the observation that the residue classes $\overline{-1}$ and $\overline{651}$ both have order two in $G$. In a cyclic group there could be only one.

In general the group $\Bbb{Z}_{m}^*$ is cyclic if and only if $m=2,4$, power of an odd prime $p$, or two times a power of an odd prime. Your modulus $1300=2^2\cdot5^2\cdot13$, so none of those apply.